# Нейронная сеть для генерации изображений по примерам

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть пары изображений: вход-выход. Существует ли нейронная сеть, которую можно натренировать на наборе этих пар так, чтобы при подаче на ее вход новых изображений, она выдавала выходное изображение по принципу из обучающего набора (там он есть)?
Если готовых решений нет, то в какую сторону копать?
Есть рабочие GANы, например StyleGan от Nvidia, которые создают уникальные изображения, на основе базы существующих, типа This Person / Cat / House и т.п. Does Not Exist, но это не тот принцип, как я понимаю.
В качестве примера: есть набор пар изображений авто: поврежденное - после ремонта. Я тренирую сеть, и подаю на вход изображение поврежденного авто, на выходе она выдает изображение уже отремонтированного.

Answer (score 3):

Готовой такой нейронки вы вряд-ли найдете.  А что-то подобное - попробуйте найти вот тут
https://neurohive.io/ru/novosti/
Я бы искал что-то в области предсказания "старения" лиц, исправления дефектов фото или восстановления лица, полузакрытого маской.
А потом -либо по аналогии, либо напрямую обратившись к авторам.